# Recovering lost save files from factory reset PS4

Tags: ps4, hard-drive

While I wasn't home, my roommates factory reset my PS4 because they encountered some error. My account did not have PS+ so I lost a lot of savedata for all my games.

I was wondering if there was any way of recovering the files. I have used the EaseUS software to try to recover files from the PS4 hdd, and it found some deleted files. However, I am not sure which files to recover, and if I could actually put them back onto the HDD somehow.

The EaseUS software shows these files:
[image]

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: PS4 HDD is encrypted. There is no way to recover the data. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

when the hard drive factory-reset, it deleted all user content. It's unlikely you could recover them from recovery software, and the files in your image seem to have no relation to the PS4.